# Where can I double check my elliptic curve results?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to do some elliptic curve calculations by hand, just to refresh myself on how the system works. I calculated some points and did some operations by hand. I am trying to double check my work with some web calculators, but I have tried several different calculators and each gives me a different result...

Is there a verified implementation or library somewhere that I could use, rather than pet projects that people have on their websites?

I am working with the curve

$y^2 \equiv x^3 - 2 \pmod 7$

I calculated the points to be

$(3,2),(3,5),(4,1),(4,6,),(5,2,),(5,5),(\infty, \infty)$

I calculated $(3,2) + (5,5) = (3,5)$ I'm fairly confident in this answer.

The problem I'm struggling with however is $(3,2) + (3,2) = (3,5)$. I have tried several times and have gotten the slope between the two points to be $27/4$. When I convert this to an integer $\mod 7$, I get the slope equal to either $3$ or $5$. When $m=3$, I get the point $(3,5)$. When $m=5$, I get the point $(5,1)$, which isn't on the curve, so I'm assuming I'm doing this step incorrectly.

Comment: The points $(4,1)$ and $(4,6)$ aren't on the curve. Only $1$ and $-1$ are cubes modulo 7, and they have three cube roots each, so there should be three values of $x$ for each $y$. Similarly for squares there should be two values of $y$ for each $x$. These points are $(6,2)$ and $(6,5)$ instead.

Comment: Clearly, my problem is with doing basic arithmetic in my head *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope is $5$:
$$ \frac{27}{4} = 27 \cdot 4^{-1} = 27 \cdot 2 = 5 \mod 7 $$

$$ x = 5 \cdot 5 - 3 - 3 = 19 = 5 \mod 7 $$

$$ y = 5 \cdot (3 - 5) - 2 = 5 \cdot (-2) - 2 =  5 \cdot 5 + 5 = 30 = 2 \mod 7$$

So $(3,2) + (3,2) = (5,2)$. This matches with $(3,2) + (5,5) = (3,5)$, since this shows that $(3,2)$ and $(5,5)$ are on a line which is tangent to the curve at $(3,2)$.